# Ошибка 500 при установке mpm-itk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, apache2

У меня стоит апач2, пытаюсь заставить каждый виртуальный хост работать от имени своего пользователя.
Для этого устанавливаю
`apt install libapache2-mpm-itk`

В настройках виртуального хоста прописываю

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId www-data www-data
</IfModule>
```

После перезагрузки апач, сайты выдают

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at test@test.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

лог ошибок содержит:

`[mpm_itk:warn] [pid 340] (itkmpm: pid=340 uid=33, gid=33) itk_post_perdir_config(): initgroups(www-data, 33): Operation not permitted`

Comment: Посмотрите на ваши значения LimitUIDRange/LimitGIDRange
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1042968-start-0.html

Comment: в файл конфигурации добавил строки LimitUIDRange/LimitGIDRange /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf  с лимитом 0 6000, перезагрузил апач. Но ошибка не пропала